# spans inside a div not hiding when the content is growing

Tags: css, overflow, html

```
<div style="width: 884px; overflow:hidden;position:relative;" class="fleft" id="CellHolder">
<span count="1" title="click to select" class="fleft"><a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a></span>
<span count="2" title="click to select" class="fleft"><a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a></span>
<span count="3" title="click to select" class="fleft"><a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a></span>
<span count="4" title="click to select" class="fleft"><a href="javascript:void(0)">4</a></span>
<span count="5" title="click to select" class="fleft"><a href="javascript:void(0)">5</a></span>
<span count="6" title="click to select" class="fleft"><a href="javascript:void(0)">6</a></span>
..........
</div>
```

Might be a silly question.. I'm not a css expert.. 
I have given the width of the wrapper div so that it accommodates 26 spans as I mentioned above. My requirement is that if the # of spans increases, then those extra spans should be hidden. With this code its coming to the next line. Overflow attribute in the div is not working..
should achieve this with css only.. no script..
can anyone help ??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want text to wrap to the next line you can add `white-space: nowrap` to your div styles.

Comment: I have tested it and it works for me, please provide a `codepen` or `jsfiddle` to further demonstrate the problem if you would like more help.